# How to use Enumerable.Empty<int>().AsQueryable()

Tags: c#

Is it possible to add some data, such as 123, to the "intList" variable below?

`IQueryable<int> intList = Enumerable.Empty<int>().AsQueryable();`

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an X/Y Problem. why do you need to do this, what is the use case as there is likely a more sane approach. `IQueryable` is a very special construct, its not really a `Collection` or an `IEnumerable` though they generally result in such. Likely you just want to concat or *join* (term used loosely) after the fact

Comment: Can you explain what you want from this question? You can't, but why do you want to know, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to build an "IQueryable<int> intList" that returns only a single record with a value of 123. Is that possible?

Comment: Why does it need to be `IQueryable` ? if we can understand that, we can likely help

Comment: Because I already have "IQueryable<int> intList" returning real data from the database via Linq to SQL, but depending on certain conditions, I want to return only 123 from the same "IQueryable<int> intList" variable.

Comment: Why not add the item first? `(new [] {123})..`

Comment: if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
{
    IQueryable<int?> intList = myQuery.GetCustomerData(string search); // This is the actual read data coming from the database
}
else
{
 IQueryable<int?> intList = I need to return 123 as mentioned
}

Then I access intList here regardless of whether or not string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search) is true.

Comment: `via Linq to SQL,` Do you mean Entity Framework?

Comment: @mjwills, that's exactly what I need. Thank you so much. Problem solved. How do I flag your comment as the answer/solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest one of the following options:

Either (if `intList` already exists):

```
intList = intList.AsEnumerable().Append(123).AsQueryable();
```

Or if it doesn't:

```
var intList = new List<int>(1){123}.AsQueryable();
```

*Note generally `AsQueryable` is not commonly useful - but in contexts like unit tests (which seems to be your scenario here), code like above is acceptable.*